# testing powershell gui with Powershell Studio 2015, does not function as planned

Tags: powershell

Going through the toolmaking powershell book and having a bit of trouble with the GUI part. When i do a test run of this gui, it's supposed to spit out the results into the "Results" box when I hit "OK". Right now it's not doing anything. I thought it was something wrong i did so I adjusted my code to match the sample solution the book gave but it's still not outputting anything. Anyone see anything I'm missing here?

```
#----------------------------------------------
# User Generated Script
#----------------------------------------------

$formServiceReporter_Load = {
    #TODO: Initialize Form Controls here
    $textboxComputername.Text = $env:COMPUTERNAME
}

Function Get-ServiceData
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $True, HelpMessage = "Enter a computername")]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [string]$Computername,
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [ValidateSet("Running", "Stopped")]
        [string]$Filter = "Running"
    )

    Try
    {
        Write-Verbose "Getting $filter services from $computername"
        $services = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $Computername -filter "State Like '$Filter'"
        #write selected results to the pipeline
        $services | Select Name, Displayname, State, StartMode, StartName
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Warning "Failed to get services from $Computername. $_.Exception.Message"
    }

} #end function

$buttonOK_Click = {
    #TODO: Place custom script here
    #check radio buttons to figure out what type of services to query
    $richtextboxResults.Clear()
    $richtextboxResults.Visible = $true

    if ($radiobuttonRunning.Checked)
    {
        $filter = "Running"
    }
    elseif ($radiobuttonStopped.Checked)
    {
        $filter = "Stopped"
    }

    $data = Get-ServiceData -Computername $textboxComputername.Text -Filter $filter
    $richtextboxResults.Text = ($data | Out-String).trim()
}


# --End User Generated Script--
#----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I've never used Powershell Studio, but if this is all of your code, I don't see any of the forms code.

Comment: Your code is fine, tested it, and it's OK... make sure you have all the controls with the right name, and one of the radiobutton must be selected... do you get any error message?

Comment: @EBGreen I only cropped the portion of the code i thought would be causing the problem the rest includes all the forms, i can add it if necessary.

Comment: Well, the reasdon I asked is related to Avshalom's comment. If you didn't assign the actions properly in the form then that could be the issue.

Comment: @Avshalom I confirmed that the "Running" radio button is checked by default, when I run it, I dont see any errors in the PS Studio output but the Results box is just blank... not really sure what's going on. I did adjust the get-serviceData function a little because the free edition would not let me add more than 5 controls per form so i took out the ability to search for "All" services... other than that i dont see a difference between my code and the sample solution.

Comment: @NiagNtawv this code needs 5 controls, one richtextbox, two radiobuttons, textbox and a button, so this should be enough- anyway works for me, not see any problem, you should do debug and set a breakpoint to see if the $data contains any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to recreate this.
The code works.

Based on your symptoms in the comments, $buttonOK doesnt seem to work at all.
Try to simply add `write-host "clicked"`  in the button click event to test this. If this is the case, change the name of the button and re-add the click event.
I've experienced this problem myself in PS Studio when using the name "OK". My quess is that it's either a bug or a feature related to the DialogResult where "OK" also exists.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hmm, thanks for the suggestion. I commented out the buttonOK_click part and added just the write-host "clicked" line and re-ran it but still no errors or outputs. I'll spend some more time on it later and see what's wrong. May just have to redo it.

Comment: Yes, since "clicked" never showed as output, the button isnt active for sure. I actually got the same error once I tried to recreate your project. Re-naming and re-added the click event fixed it.

Comment: think i figured out the problem. It seems like im copying the code to the clipboard and pasting it to the script editor makes it all faulty. I did a quick test by creating a richtext box and a single button. Set button_click function to something simple like $data = get-service -computername localhost $richtextbox.text = $data | out-string. Clicking the button throws the results in the text box.

Comment: went back to recreate my original project. Button seems responsive following the steps i discovered above but now it's claiming that the "term Get-ServiceData is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file...." although i have that function defined under the formServiceReporter_load function....but whatever thanks for your help i'll consider this resolved.